# HTML5 and JQuery Match Game Autoload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following tutorial to build a simple match game:

http://geeksretreat.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/html5-and-jquery-a-simple-matching-game/

The way it is built, the following javascript is needed to reveal the tiles on the initial page load. Is there a way to have the first game load immediately, without having to click "new game"? So when the user first opens the page, the tiles load and then for a new game, they could utilize the new game button. Here is the javascript that forces the user to click "new game" to load the tiles:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#startGameButton').click(function() {

    initTiles();

    setTimeout("revealTiles(function() { onPeekStart(); })",iInterval);

   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the `click` code explicitly on `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#startGameButton').click(function() {
    initTiles();
    setTimeout("revealTiles(function() { onPeekStart(); })",iInterval);
   }).trigger('click'); // or simply .click()
});
```